# iOS: Magical Record import hierarchical relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, hierarchy, magicalrecord, datamodel

I have a hierarchically-structured data representing categories, where a category has a parent category and a list of children categories.

This is being retrieved from a web service with a JSON in this form:

```
{
    id = 1;
    name = MyCategoryName;
    parentId = 328;
}
```

I have set up my Data Model as follows:

[image]

- On the `identifier`attribute I have set `mappedKeyName = id`
- On the `children` relationship I have set `relatedByAttribute = identifier`
- On the `parent` relationship I have set `mappedKeyName = parentId` and    `relatedByAttribute = identifier`

When I am using `[MR_importFromObject:inContext:]` the database contains empty rows which I believe is because MR cannot find the parent category to be set.

What am I doing wrong in the data model ? Is there any way this can be achieved using only the import functionality of Magical Record or I have to manually establish the relationship after all categories have been saved to the database ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what you were doing wrong here? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I am not sure if was doing something wrong or it is just how MR works. I had to set up the relationships manually which solved it for me. Eventually the model was changed, so this was not an issue for me anymore. I would love to find the answer for this though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up just overriding the `importChild:` method on my subclass to manually set this up.